# tbl_summary: compare 2 datasets (full and reduced)

Tags: r, gtsummary

Using `gtsummary` and `tbl_summary` function I would like to compare my full dataset with a reduced dataset (same data but lower number of individuals).

See example below (full dataset with 197 individuals, reduced dataset with 167 individuals)
[image: table]

Maybe I can store each `tbl_summary` in an objects and compare both?
My goal is to show that the reduced dataset is comparable to the full dataset.
Thanks !

Comment: how are the data reduced? by what variable? can you just stratify by the variable you are creating the reduce cohort by and `add_p()`? please share code and data

Comment: the dataset is reduced by deleting individuals with incomplete data `df <- drop_na(df,sexe_mascu)`, I cannot use add_p() because these are two separate datasets (and two differents `tbl_summary`)

Comment: Statistically you can't really compare the reduced cohort to the full cohort because the observations are not independent. Instead of dropping people with missing `sexe_mascu` created a indicator variable with people have it and those who do not and use that indicator in the by argument in tbl_summary